# How to create an Oracle database from Rational Rose?

Tags: oracle, rational-rose

Please I am trying to create an Oracle database in Rational Rose but the option is deactivated:

[image]

Did I need to install an Oracle client first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finded why:
I must right click in the Components View, not in the Logical View